# SharePoint is not installed error in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, error, deployment

I have a solution I'm keeping all my specific projects inside. I can easily deploy existing one and even add new Visual Web Parts and redeploy. But when trying to add a new project I get the error 'The required version of SharePoint .. is not installed on this system'

This is something new I have just started getting. Could it be due to a recent Content DB sync from production? Could permissions have been brought down on the DB in our Development environment?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using the right templates: there are templates for SharePoint 2013 and templates for 2010. You'll get this error if you have 2013 installed but pick the 2010 visual studio project template.

Comment: I'm such an idiot haha. it's Monday :P